# Angular.js + require.js + jQuery Plugin custom directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Angular and Require, my question is regarding the following piece of code (I have already hooked up angular and require, I can include files if asked); the bootstrap-switch element is not being initialized :

```
define(['myapp.ui/module', function (module) {
module.directive('bootstrapSwitch', ['$parse', '$path', function ($parse, $path) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element) {
            //load requirements for this directive.
            console.log(element.bootstrapSwitch);
            element.bootstrapSwitch();
        }
    };
    return require([
        'myapp.ui/switch/bootstrap-switch.min',
        'css!myapp.ui/switch/bootstrap-switch.min'],
        function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                replace: false,
                link: function (scope, element) {
                    //load requirements for this directive.
                    element.bootstrapSwitch();
                }
            };
        });
}]);
```

}]);

I am able to see the directive file being loaded (the one above), but the element is not initialized, I fail to see bootstrap-switch.min.css and bootstrap-switch.min.js (I know the paths are working, I'm sure I have a sintax problem somewhere. If not, please elaborate.  Any help would be appreciated!!!!

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax problem 1:

Change:

```
define(['myapp.ui/module', function (module) {
```

To:

```
define(['myapp.ui/module'], function (module) {
```

Also, consider using a different argument name than 'module' since it can be confused with an AMD module. (The module called 'module' is a special module that refers to the loaded module itself.)

Syntax problem 2:

The second `return` statement won't do anything. Perhaps you wanted to include all dependencies in the outer `define`:

```
define([
    'myapp.ui/module',
    'myapp.ui/switch/bootstrap-switch.min',
    'css!myapp.ui/switch/bootstrap-switch.min'
], function (ui) {
```

Answer (score 0):

not possible to return another thing after return statement. if the require statement try to load some dependencies, you could put it in the define first parameter.

Comment: As in: define(['myapp.ui/module', 'myapp.ui/switch/bootstrap-switch.min', ..]) etc?